# iOS library to view 3D STEP files (.stp)

Tags: ios, 3d, step

I already searched the web for a library I can use in my iOS project to show 3D STEP files.
...without success.

Does anyone of you know about a library that can show real 3D STEP files without converting them?

...or does anyone know of an App (that's available in the App Store) that can show STEP files without converting them into another file format before?

Appreciate your help!

Thx,
Dennis

Answer (score 2):

Most STEP files contain BREP/NURBS geometry, which has to be converted to triangles for visualization with graphics libraries like DirectX, OpenGL, or WebGL.   For open source, you may want to look at OpenCascade (OCCT and OCE), pythonOCC, FreeCAD, BRL-CAD, and STEPcode.